# Jquery, on click, hide div & replace with hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if i'm doing this right. Or if this is the best way to do it.

Basically what i want is : on click on the `#button_3`, it hides my `#content` div and shows the `#form` div. My form div is set to `display:none` .

Cheers!

```
$("#button_3").on("click", function(e){
        $("#content").hide(function(this)
        $("#form").show();
        )};
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$("#button_3").on("click", function(e){
     $("#content").hide();
     $("#form").show();
});
```

If you want performance, then use `bind()` instead of `on()` because it is the fastest.

See the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-bind-click-vs-jquery-click/2)

Answer (score 1):

do like this:

```
$("#button_3").click(function(){
     $("#content").hide();
     $("#form").show();
});
```